# show that in a simple graph, any closed walk of odd length contains a cycle

Tags: graph-theory

is there anyone can prove me that? actually I didn't understand what does that mean literally? is not a closed walk already a cycle? what does this question mean? thanks in advance.

Comment: That would be called a circuit (or in some books a closed tour), which is not necessarily a cycle (which has no "internal" repreated vertices).

Answer (score 1):

A cycle is a closed walk without repeated edges. And "contains" may be taken a bit broad. For example a closed walk $adabebcfca$ conrains the cycle $abca$.

Comment: so why is it say "odd-length"? i still didn't understand the question exactly.

Comment: @WhoCares for even walks it is not true, take for example the closed walk $aba$, it doesn't contain a cycle.

Comment: @:Hagen  **why a closed even walk need not contain a cycle ** ? i know the proof for odd length Cycle ...can you please help me out for **even length walk**